# Is it safe to execute SQL query like this in Python using MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I've notice most sources say to best practice to execute SQL statements in Python is something like this:

```
cursor.execute( 'select * from coworkers where name = :1 and clue > :2', [ name, clue_threshold ] )
```

Other sources say

```
cursor.execute( "select * from coworkers where name = %s and clue > %s", ( name, clue_threshold ) )
```

which I think is pretty similar.

Anyway the way I have been doing is creating a dictionary and storing values. For example, the initial dictionary `biz_info` looks like this:

```
biz_info = {
    'business'     : None,
    'name'         : None,
    'neighborhood' : None,
    'address'      : None,
    'city'         : None,
    'state'        : None,
    'zip_code'     : None,
    'latitude'     : None,
    'longitude'    : None,
    'phone'        : None,
    'url'          : None,
    'yelp_url'     : None,
}
```

then I execute the SQL statement like this

```
execute_sql( cur, "insert into " + TABLE_BIZ_NAME + """ values (
                   NULL,
                   %(name)s,
                   %(neighborhood)s,
                   %(address)s,
                   %(city)s,
                   %(state)s,
                   %(zip_code)s,
                   %(latitude)s,
                   %(longitude)s,
                   %(phone)s,
                   %(url)s,
                   %(yelp_url)s,
                   NULL
                   )"""
                   , biz_info )
```

Is this safe against sql injections? I want to use dictionaries to store information because it's easier to manage.

To be honest, I'm not even entirely sure what the difference between using a `%`, `,`, `%s`, `%d`, and `%()s` means in parameterized queries. Basically all I know is **not** to use

```
cursor.execute( "select * from coworkers where name = '%s' and clue > %d" % ( name, clue_threshold ) )
```

Comment: "Is this safe against sql injections?".  Yes.  "I'm not even entirely sure what the difference between using a %, ,, %s, %d, and %()s means in parameterized queries".  Does this mean you're asking about the rules for the Python DB-API?   Are you asking about this http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way used to pass parameters to sql command strings depends on the database (sqlite, for example, uses `?`).

According to [MySQLdb documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html), you can use `paramstyle` parameter to set the preferred way to format a string (`format` or `pyformat`).

The first example in your question doesn't seem to be supported. Anyway, I'd say that as long as you don't format the whole string as in the last example, you're safe since it can be assumed that the query parameters will be properly escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Your insert statement should really explicitly specify the field names to be set, to guard against breakages from schema changes. Also, I find your code too repetitive. I would write the insert something more like this:

```
cursor.execute \
  (
        "insert into "
    +
        TABLE_BIZ_NAME
    +
        "("
    +
        ", ".join(biz_info.keys())
    +
        ") values ("
    +
        ", ".join(("%s",) * len(biz_info))
    +
        ")",
    biz_info.values()
  )
```

This way, the field names only need to be listed once, in the creation of the biz_info dict. And any future changes only need them to be updated there.

Comment: I like how you use `join()` and `keys()`. Thanks for the tip!